# New emulator backend requires minimum kernel version 3.10+ (currently got lower)

Tags: android, emulation

when I use “`emulator -data smsReceiver`”，then “emulator: ERROR: New emulator back-end requires minimum kernel version 3.10+ (currently got lower)
Please make sure you've got updated system images and do not force the specific kernel image together with the engine version”
As a beginner,

I don't know how to solve it.